# Export SSRS Reports to PDF with Python Script

Tags: sql, python-3.x, reporting-services, pdf-generation

I have number of SSRS reports that I would like to be able to export to PDF using Python. What's the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Have you checked out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver15)? You can manipulate the URL for direct exporting.

Comment: You can have a look at this https://pypi.org/project/sspyrs/